# With Axiom of Choice, if $\langle A,\prec\rangle$ is well ordered then A has no subset of order type $\omega^*$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

The question is raised when I look at this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31990/with-choice-is-any-linearly-ordered-set-well-ordered-if-no-subset-has-order-typ) which have been asked three years ago. 
I want to know if the other side of the question is still true or to be more specific :-

> With Axiom of Choice, if  $\langle A,\prec\rangle$  is well ordered then $A$ has no subset of order type $\omega^*$.

Comment: I am sorry,I supposed to write the converse of the earlier question.Now I corrected and I am looking for the converse. thanks

Comment: You don’t need the axiom of choice for this: if $A$ has a subset of order type $\omega^*$, then by definition $\langle A,\prec\rangle$ is not a well-order.

Comment: that was my big concern, why the the problem asked to use axiom of choice. but now I understand,its needed for the other part only.thanks

Comment: Yes, that’s right. You’re welcome.

Comment: The axiom of choice is needed for the other implication. If there is no embedding of $\omega^*$ into $\langle A,\prec\rangle$, then it is well-ordered.

Comment: But as we saw in the answer of the earlier post even we need weaker version of AC ( I mean DC).

Comment: For the other direction. The question you link asks about ***the other implication***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be shown even without choice: assume that $B\subseteq A$ has order type $\omega*$ when considered with $\prec$. Then $B$ has no minimal element, which says, by definition of well-order, that $A$ is not a well-order.